# Desktop-like layout using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a web application that should behave more or less like a desktop app, with the following features:

- It must take all the browser space (100% width and height, no scrolling), with the following 4 main elements:

  - A header. It will contain the main menu. It must be fixed to top.
  - A left sidebar with an object pane.
  - The main content area, right to the sidebar, where it will display a grid and data. Must be scrollable when content is large.
  - A footer fixed to the bottom of the screen, only visible when the user double click on an object of the left sidebar. It also has to be collapsable by clicking on an 'X' button on the upper right border.

The tricky part is that, when I double click on an object, the footer (about 150-200px) must be visible and show the object data. Both the sidebar and the main content area must shrink in height so the footer doesn't overlap them, and they are back to full height when the user closes the footer.

Is it possible to do such a layout using Bootstrap framework? I've been playing around with it but I couldn't get it working correctly...

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: SO is not a coding service. It's expected that you'll the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you please provide some sort of code that you've been "playing around with"?  Help us help you!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting such a generic question, I was tired after spending all the day doing tests on bootply without finding an appropiate solution so I decided to ask here.

I've decided to move from Bootstrap to Foundation, as it provides the exact feature I was looking for on its XY Grid. Using this framework, my application layout will be as simple as this:

```
<div class="grid-y medium-grid-frame">
  <div class="cell shrink header medium-cell-block-container">

    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->

  </div>

  <div class="cell medium-auto medium-cell-block-container">

    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
      <div class="cell medium-4 medium-cell-block-y">

        <!-- SIDEBAR -->

      </div>

      <div class="cell medium-8 medium-cell-block-y">

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="cell shrink footer">

    <!-- FOOTER -->

  </div>
</div>
```

I'll be more concise next time, cheers!

Comment: Here's a codepen that illustrates this with a bit more detail: [https://codepen.io/ZURBFoundation/pen/MogrXG]

Comment: Hi! Can you double check the link? It seems it's not working... Thanks! :)

Comment: Here's a codepen that illustrates this with a bit more detail: https://codepen.io/ZURBFoundation/pen/MogrXG